# Uni-Directional text editor Rtl And bidi?

Tags: text-editor, bidirectional, bidi

I have a problem regarding rendering Arabic letters in a normal situation Arabic letters are rendered from right to left except numbers that's exactly what i want to do i want to make it full RTL not just the letters.
I have found a way of doing it in html and css but to build a text editor in these two and of course electron is a terrible idea, the implementation though is through using :

```
direction: rtl;
unicode-bidi: bidi-override;
```

but these two options i have not found any equivalent behavior in any Gui frameworks like qt and swing or at least i couldn't find one.
the desired behavior when i type Arabic letter followed by a numbers is that numbers also is inserted from right to left.